# Get all wikiquote *content* under a category and subcategories

Tags: api, web-scraping, wikipedia

Consider the pages listed under [this catscan](http://tools.wmflabs.org/catscan2/catscan2.php?language=sa&project=wikiquote&depth=1&categories=%E0%A4%B8%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%AD%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B7%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%A4%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A8%E0%A4%BF&ns%5B0%5D=1&ns%5B14%5D=1&get_q=1&doit=1). I want to get a csv where each row corresponds to one article (say [this](https://sa.wikiquote.org/wiki/%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%8B%E0%A4%95%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%B2%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A8%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%82_%E0%A4%B8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%8B_%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%82%E0%A4%AA%E0%A4%82...) for the example below), and the line is of the form:

```
"कोकिलानां स्वरो रूपं...", "कोकिलानां स्वरो रूपं स्त्रीणां रूपं पतिव्रतम् । \n विद्या रूपं कुरूपाणां क्षमा रूपं तपस्विनाम् ॥"
```

What is the simplest way of accomplishing this?